# SQL Query IF ELSE in Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

How can i add if else statement in my sql query in codeigniter

Here is my code:

```
$this->datatables->select(
                        'a.id,
                        c.capital_buildup,
                        a.loan_no,
                        a.member_no,
                        b.loan_type_name,
                        a.loan_amount,
                        a.terms,
                        a.date_applied,
                        IF(status = "Approved", "Approved","Pending")', //i want to add else statement here
                        FALSE);
```

The outcome query that I want is this

```
 If( status = "Approved")
      //Approved
 else if (status = "Disapproved")
     //Disapproved
 else
     //Pending
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is easier to express using a [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html), something like;

```
CASE WHEN status = "Approved"    THEN "This is approved" 
     WHEN status = "Disapproved" THEN "This is disapproved"
                                 ELSE "This is pending"
END
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
$this->datatables->select(
                    'a.id,
                    c.capital_buildup,
                    a.loan_no,
                    a.member_no,
                    b.loan_type_name,
                    a.loan_amount,
                    a.terms,
                    a.date_applied,
                    CASE WHEN status = "Approved"    THEN "approved statement" 
                         WHEN status = "Disapproved" THEN "disapproved statement"
                                                     ELSE "pending statement"
                                                     END AS status',

                    FALSE);
```

Isaksson already defined the `case statement`. It's in CI format.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get all rows in array. And than use FOREACH to unset values with disproved.

```
`foreach($result as $k => $row)
{  
if($row['status'] == "approved")
{     
$approved[] = $row;    
}
if($row['status'] == "disapproved")   
{ $disapproved[] = $row;}
}`
```

I never tested that. i hope this could work.

Comment: I know how to get values I need how to query if else in sql select statement